# use 7inch raspberry pi lcd board for tv lcd

Tags: lcd

i have a board like this http://banlinhkien.vn/images/201701/goods_img/5375_P_1483585464340.jpg
I also have an 30 pins lvds lcd tv panel(its main board is broken).So my plan is use that raspberry pi main board to drive 30 pins lvds lcd screen.But i need the diagram or pinout of the board convert to standard 30pins lvds so i'm asking here hope that i can fix my tv soon.